# Unit Tests will not run when downloading zip of github project, but work correctly when cloning from command line

Tags: unit-testing, github

In my GitHub account when downloading my repository by clicking the Code tab and then clicking the Clone or download button and choosing 'Download ZIP', my solution will build but no unit test will run. They don't fail but just don't run. Instead if I clone the repository with the `git clone` command, all of the unit tests run. Does anyone have any idea why this would occur?

Comment: What do you mean by not run? Are you executing some command where you expect it to run but it does not?

Comment: In Visual Studio when I click Test then Run All Tests, it appears as if the tests will run, but none pass and none fail. They all have an exclamation point next to them and above the tests where the exclamation point is it says 21 not run tests. One difference I noticed when using the project from the downloaded zip is that Visual Studio asked if I trusted the source. I said yes, but I wonder if that is causing something to be blocked.

Comment: When you download a zip file for a commit, it contains only a copy of the files in that given commit.  It isn't a Git repository and doesn't contain any history.  That may or may not be relevant here.

Comment: @bk2204 I think that must have been the problem since cloning the repository worked as I was expecting but downloading the zip did not.